# Parent and child parameterized constructor in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

Normal testing for Parent and child constructors in Java, so I use parameterized constructors in both parent and child class,
But I didn't get the right output.

```
class A {

    A(int i) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}



class B extends A {

    B(int i, int j) {
        System.out.println(i+j);
    }
}



public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {    
        B b = new B(5,7);
    }
}
```

Comment: add `super(i);` in the `B` constructor at the very beginning. Next time, please, specify what "the right output" is

Comment: What you got, then?

Comment: What output you are expecting

Comment: Your code does not compile. That's a difference to "I didn't get the right output".

Answer (score 0):

**Class B** extends **Class A** which has a non-empty constructor.
So when we try to construct an instance of **Class B**, we should call the parent constructor first
By calling `super(...)` keyword

```
super(integerValue);
```